# How to find an EVEN number factorial in python?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, numbers, factorial

So I have to define a function called def factorial_evens(num): and 'num' will be any number greater than 1. My problem is that I have to calculate a factorial of 'num' using only the even numbers in num.

So for example, if num = 6, then the factorial would equal 48 as opposed to 720.

My current code is only able to do regular factorials with even number inputs but will not do factorials with the even numbers in 'num'.

```
def factorial_evens(num):
    num = 6
    if num % 2 == 0:
        product = 1       
        for i in range(num):
            product = product * (i+1)
        print(product)
```

Comment: Just replace your loop : `for i in range(1, num, 2):`

Comment: I'm sorry but wouldn't that limit the range to 2? EDIT: It worked! Would you mind explaining how?

Comment: So, if `num` were, there would be no output? @hashcode55 `range(2, num + 1, 2)`?

Comment: @Pritster5 It means "iterate from 1 to num with an interval of 2".

Comment: @hashcode55 Ah I see, so it skips the over the range in intervals of 2? That makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: FWIW, this function is known as the [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial), or sometimes the semifactorial (which is a more sensible name, IMHO).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your conditional was in the wrong place. This looks like what you tried, but should work.

```
def factorial_evens(num):
     product = 1       
     for i in range(num):
         if (i % 2 == 1):
             product = product * (i+1)
     print(product)
```

It would be better to use  a stride in the range declaration to save yourself some effort

```
def factorial_evens(num):
    product = 1
    for i in range(2, num+1, 2):
        product *= i
    print(product)
```

Comment: You want `num + 1` in `range` I believe.

Answer (score 1):

One straightforward way: use the step parameter to `range` and adjust the input to be even...

```
def factorial_evens(num):
    if num < 0:
        raise ValueError("argument must be non-negative")
    if num % 2 == 1:
        num -= 1
    result = 1
    for x in range(num, 0, -2):
        result *= x
    return result
```

In action:

```
In [3]: factorial_evens(6)
Out[9]: 48

In [4]: factorial_evens(7)
Out[4]: 48

In [5]: factorial_evens(8)
Out[5]: 384
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the range, filter the odd ones, reduce them, here the functional aproach:

```
from functools import reduce
import operator
def fact_evens(num):
    return reduce(operator.mul, filter(lambda x: x%2 == 0, range(1, num+1)))


fact_evens(6)
48
```

Much better, dont filter, just jump 2 by 2 in the range:

```
reduce(operator.mul, range(1, num+1, 2))
```

**EDIT**: for python2, just use `reduce` and `xrange`

Comment: This is python 2 and OP probably uses Python 3 but other than that great answer

Comment: strange to import functools to use reduce if python 2 right. way to go, just minor nitpick anyway. Using `range` works for both and given the size of `num` shouldn't hog the memory...

Comment: sorry guys, I have a mix from python2-3, ill edit to explain

Comment: Why not `reduce(int.__mul__, range(2, num+1, 2), 1)`?

Comment: Won't `range(1, num+1, 2)` only get odd numbers?

Comment: @PM2Ring, `__` methods are not intended to being used like that, even if you can.